# Help to Install Eclipse for A Netbeans Users

Tags: java

I had been using Netbeans all the while to develop Swing application. So far, I am a **Happy Netbeans User**

Currently, I had a project (GWT, J2EE and Swing), which I need to use Eclipse (Please do not ask Why)

Here is the step I had been taken.

1. Download *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (190 MB)* from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ I thought this should be the correct choice, as I see most features are found in that edition http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages
2. After struggling a while to get use to the user interface of Eclipse, I still cannot find a **Visual GUI Editor**!
3. After doing some Googling, I realize I need to install something called **Plugins**

However, tones of plugins which had similar features has confused me, as I found

http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/index.html

http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/main.php

http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/

This makes me even more confuse? Which plugin I should use to develop a Swing based application? Most of them seems not up-to-dated. Or, is there any complete bundle I can download, where 1 click, will install all the necessary Swing development tools for me?

**I just miss my Netbeans :( I really appreciate their team, who make the installation work so easy. One click button install, all the necessary tools just come to me**

Comment: Each IDE has its pros and cons - this you're mentioning is just one of such cases.

Comment: Can someone update the title of this question to make it clearer that this is about getting a plugin for Eclipse? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse users typically program UI by hand.

Comment: I never able to deliver a GUI desktop application to happy client on time, without a GUI designer. For those able to do that, I take my hat off.